# Convert YYYYMMDD string to Date using Attributes

Tags: c#, datetime, filehelpers

I am using FileHelper to populate data from a CSV File. 
The file has date in a  YYYYMMDD string.

for example

19880312,20120505,20121231 ...

the model for the same is

```
class PatientData
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth{get;set;}
    //Some Other Columns
}
```

the code for import is :

```
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(PatientData));
PatientData[] clientes = (PatientData[])engine.ReadFile(@"Path to CSV");
```

the problem I am having is 20121212 is being converted to 20th Dec 1212 (DDMMYYYY)instead of YYYYMMDD.

Tried using attributes on DateTime but dont know how to get the initial string value in them.

TIA

Comment: What's the code you use to get the date?

Comment: the `engine.ReadFile` automatically assigns the date according to the model

Comment: DateTime is a DateTime You can't change it - You can only format the way it's displayed.

Comment: Do you have access to the engine.ReadFile source code?

Comment: I just googled for FileHelperEngine and [found something](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_generics.html) like `[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")]` as an attribute. If this is the library you are using you could try that (with a different format of course).

Comment: Take notice on your date format string. Check the full list of options [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). There is no uppercase YYYY pattern in c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to annotate your property with the `FieldConverterAttribute`. Here is a link to the official documentation http://www.filehelpers.net/quickstart/

Something like this will do the trick.

```
public class PatientData
{
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyyMMdd")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth{ get; set; }
    //Some Other Columns
}
```

Take notice on your date format string. Check the full list of options [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). There is no uppercase YYYY pattern in c#.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FieldConverterAttribute](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.FieldConverterAttribute.html) and [ConverterKind](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.ConverterKind.html) and decorate your property this way:

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyyMMdd")]
```